# How to Write CSS Code for Mozilla Firefox Browser

Tags: css

i am using following css code for displaying flash text in my website. Flash Text Displaying in Chrome Browser nicely but not in Mozilla Firefox Browser. if i add this code width:650px; position: absolute; in css, displaying flash text in mozilla firebos nicely but not in chrome browser again. what should i do ??

.flash_text { padding-left: 50px; margin-left: 50px; }

**Chrome Browser**

**Flash News** : Training Programme on Personality Development

**Mozilla Browser**

**Flash News** :

```
            Training Programme on Personality Development
```

how to make it proper display in both browser

the following css code working nicely for chrome browser

.flash_text { padding-left: 50px; margin-left: 50px; }

but not to Mozilla Browser

if i add this coding **width:650px; position: absolute;** displaying nicely but again chrome browser not displaying properly 
what to do??

Comment: make a jsfiddle to show us what you have right now, then ask your question and tell us what you have tried before starting this question. You question is too vague, there is no way anyone can answer this.

Comment: Ummmm what is Firebox? Also where is your HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    h1 {
        color: red;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This should be red in FF</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

All 3 browsers

```
<style type='text/css'>
/*This will work for chrome */
                    #categoryBackNextButtons
                    {
                        width:490px;
                    }
/*This will work for firefox*/
                    @-moz-document url-prefix() {
                        #categoryBackNextButtons{
                        width:486px;
                    }
                    }
                </style>
                <!--[if IE]>
                <style type='text/css'>
/*This will work for IE*/
                #categoryBackNextButtons
                {
                    width:486px;
                }
                </style>
                <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Flash News Not Displaying properly in Mozilla Firebox browser but it is displaying nicely in Chrome Browser

Comment: i am using class name is .flash_text. so how to declare here class name?